# Cloud Endpoints in Eclipse using Maven

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

How to build and deploy a Java app with its Maven dependencies on Google Endpoints using Eclipse. This guide [Getting Started with Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) provides an introduction, but it doesn't mention how to build the project in Eclipse and deploy to the cloud using a Google SDK plugin for Eclipse (I need similar instruction as in this [tutorial here](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating-new-webapp), but for Cloud Endpoints).

**Edit:**
Let me put it another way:
I am in Eclipse and I click on "Google App Engine Flexible Java Project", then a default project is generated along with its configuration files (pom.xml, etc). The problem is that this project is not an "Endpoints" project, because it doesn't have files like "openapi-appengine.yaml" or "openapi.yaml". There must be a standard way that generates an Endpoints project just like we do for a web app. I couldn't find a document/page in Google Cloud documentation that describes how to use the Cloud Tools plugin in Eclipse to generate an Endpoints project.

**NOTE:**

This question has a chosen answer, but it is still not the optimal way to go. If you can improve it please do.

If anyone from Google is monitoring this question's tags and reads this please advise.

Comment: Try installing the google cloud for Eclipse 1.5.0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few days trying to get it to work in Eclipse, I came to a conviction that an Endpoints project can't be built entirely and tested in Eclipse and then uploaded to App Engine.

Here is what I did instead. If anyone has a better answer, please post it.

**Solution:**

1. Use [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine) to create a dummy 'Hello, World' project.
2. Modify its EchoServlet.java class to include your application code.
3. Modify the pom.xml file to include all the dependencies that you use in your application.
4. Deploy the API to App Engine  and test it.

**Drawback:**
There is a problem with this that you can't test any new functionality without impacting the live app since you would have to redeploy and test it directly on App Engine. I wanted to do this on a local machine using Eclipse (build and test) before deploying to App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tutorial for Maven: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java and I don't know about that Eclipse plugin (using Gradle instead), in a regular terminal the command to deploy should be `mvn appengine:deploy` - or to run it locally: https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging; it's a [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/index.php) project.

you are also using an obsoleted Eclipse plugin; better use [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) instead.

[image: Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse]

Comment: Actually, I posted the wrong URL in my question. That tutorial was what I followed, but it clones the project from a Github repository. My aim is to build the code in Eclipse and deploy. I will update the URL in the question.

Comment: @me._ this is just the "Hello World" of App engine, while you might need to convert it to Maven eclipse.org/m2e project; or create further custom "external commands", which automate things from the IDE. those project creation wizards are not much different from a sample project with one merely empty page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do use Cloud Tools. I don't think my point is clear, let me put it another way: so I am in Eclipse and I click on "Google App Engine Flexible Java Project", then a default project is generated along with its configuration files (pom.xml, etc). The problem is that this project is not an "Endpoints" project, because it doesn't have files like "openapi-appengine.yaml" or "openapi.yaml". Do I create them manually, there must be a standard way that generates an Endpoints project just like we do for a web app.

Comment: @me._ you might also require the "Endpoints Framework Maven plugin" to generate these files ... https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks and there also is a specific tutorial available: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java

Comment: @me._ this is the current Endpoints framework JAR, most likely required: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework-all/2.0.10

Comment: I know this is an old post.  But I don't want to use Maven.

Comment: This has little to do with `mvn`, except using the `mavenCentral()` repository.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement, for any existing sizeable standard appengine project where you have >50-100 of dependencies(including transitive ones) to manage, Eclipse alone would not do the magic! You essentially need to to integrate some effective dependency management and build tool like Maven or Graddle.

I recently migrated/upgraded our App engine Standard java project from Cloud Endpoints framework V1 to V2. This was not easy exercise for a large existing project.
Most painful part was the conflicting jars and conflicting versions of same jars/dependencies.

In past, We had tried and spent a lot of time to handle these issues with just Eclipse(and its plugins eco-system) alone as converting eclipse java project into Maven java project needed lot of change with some good learning curve as well, which was not an option then.

Only recently, we converted our eclipse java project into Maven one and things got easy with its strong dependency management tools. Moreover, GPE has deprecated now and you need to upgrade to Cloud SDK based development/deployment model and here Maven comes very handy. Esp. for Datanucleus enhancement and Endpoints framework integration, Maven/Graddle would eliminate lot of friction.

Would strongly recommend to convert your legacy project into Maven one if not.
@Martin Zeitler points to right direction.